# How to make part of HTML page responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like to make only a part of a HTML page responsive to certain width leaving all the rest responsive to the browser size.

**Example:** In a web page, the user can design grids with text and images. The user can change the width of the entire layout. So, when the user changes the width of the layout of a design, only that layout becomes responsive set to the width chosen by the user.

In other words, the part of the design becomes responsive to the width set by the user while the rest of the web pages stay responsive to the browser size.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly, but if I have, then you can simply use `%`. If a `600px` width parent element has a child element with a width set to `50%`, then the width of the child will be `300px`. If the parent width is then reduced to `400px`, the width of the child will automatically reduce to `200px`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:
[image]

Comment: Kind of. The pink part has to be responsive to the entire width. The blue part has to be responsive too but to the width that is thinner than the pink part. Thanks in advance to your time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/bGByxaQ

HTML

```
<head>  
....
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head> 

....  
<div class="responsive">
  <h1>this content is reponsive</h1>
  <p>....</p>
</div>
<div class="user-content">
   <h1>This content set by user</h1>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.responsive {
   /* as required */
}

.user-content {
  /* width and other values set by user */
  width: 1500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yes, kind of.
But how you set the pink background to be responsive to the browser? Just naming the class "responsive"? I'm sorry I could not understand completely.

Comment: Hi @DanielsonSilva , 
> But how you set the pink background to be responsive to the browser?

The responsive behaviour is set by the viewport meta tag in the head of the document. Does this make sense? I can send more details if needed.

Comment: In your example, I clicked on the link. The pink part is resizing when I shrink the browser. I guess the width: 100%; is the default value of width.

Comment: Yes, the default width of the pink div is 100%, and you could change this to anything you like by adding CSS details to the .responsive selector.

Comment: A partial correction to my first comment. The viewport meta tag is needed so that your page remains responsive on mobile.  You can add whatever content you like in the pink div, but you want to ensure that what you add also remains responsive. For example, when specifying widths (in the pink div), consider using relative units like % or vw as opposed to pixels. You may also need to use @media queries. Good luck!